# Does my motherboard support the NVIDIA RTX A6000 GPU?

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, pc

Back in early 2022 my brother built my amazing PC for me, sadly he is no longer with us.

He was the always the hardware guy and I was software guy. So I am out of my depth but I really want to figure it out.

I am looking to upgrade to a GPU that is much more optimal for my line of work, which is cleaning and editing dense scanned 3D data (Photogrammetry). A lot of the workstations at my workplace use the [NVIDIA RTX A6000](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/design-visualization/rtx-a6000/) and I really like its performance.

I want to upgrade my GPU to the A600, but I am having a hard time figuring out if the other parts of my PC will be compatible with it.

My  current build consists of:

- CPU - [Ryzel 9 5950x](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-5950x)
- GPU - [Nvidia RTX3090](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/graphics-cards/30-series/rtx-3090-3090ti/) (Not the 3090 Ti)
- Motherboard - [Asus ProArt X570-CREATOR WIFI](https://www.asus.com/uk/motherboards-components/motherboards/proart/proart-x570-creator-wifi/)
- Power Supply - [Seasonic PRIME-TX-1600](https://amzn.eu/d/7EdA3fV)
- Case - [Fractal Design Meshify 2 XL ATX Full Tower Case](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/product/49bCmG/fractal-design-meshify-2-xl-atx-full-tower-case-fd-c-mes2x-01)
- Memory - 128GB of RAM
- 8TB of [Samsung SSD](https://amzn.eu/d/dKYXGWT)

How do I do determine if the NVIDIA RTX A6000 will fit in the case?

How do I determine if  my current motherboard is compatible with the NVIDIA RTX A6000?

How do I determine if  my current CPU is compatible with my the NVIDIA RTX A6000?

How do I determine if my current PSU will provide optimal power for entire build, (once the NVIDIA RTX A6000 is added)?

Any help and insight would be most appreciated!

Comment: Please add the name of the app you are using, not just the area , it'll be easier for us to help you. Also, are you sure it is the GPU which needs an upgrade? https://www.pugetsystems.com/solutions/photogrammetry-workstations/realitycapture/hardware-recommendations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I do determine if the NVIDIA RTX A6000 will fit in the case?

The specific model of the [A6000](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/design-visualization/rtx-a6000/) that you linked says it is 10.5" long. If you're shopping for a different manufacturer/model of A6000 just make note of the length from that manufacturer's specifications webpage.
Your case is the [Meshify 2 XL](https://www.fractal-design.com/products/cases/meshify/meshify-2-xl-dark-tempered-glass/dark-tempered-glass/) which fits GPUs up to 13.3" (340mm) so there is no concern here about whether the A6000 will fit. FYI this case can fit even longer GPUs if you remove the metal structure for the hard drives, then it can fit practically any GPU ever.

> How do I determine if my current motherboard is compatible with the NVIDIA RTX A6000?

The RTX A6000 requires a PCIe 16x slot, ideally that should be PCIe 4.0 but the GPU is backwards compatible. The physical dimensions of PCIe has never changed, and they almost always have forwards & backwards compatibility to allow old motherboards to use new GPUs, or old GPUs to work in new motherboards.
Your motherboard is new enough to have PCIe 4.0 so there is no concern about losing performance anyway. The A6000 will fit and it will be compatible with the motherboard.

> How do I determine if my current CPU is compatible with my the NVIDIA RTX A6000?

There isn't really a case where a specific CPU and GPU would be incompatible unelss it's something unusual like vendor-locked hardware for servers, or an engineering sample that's missing entire features. In general you can trust that any retail consumer CPU will support any GPU, there are standards to ensure this stuff "just works".

> How do I determine if my current PSU will provide optimal power for entire build, (once the NVIDIA RTX A6000 is added)?

The specs page for the A6000 (again, make note of the specs for whatever model you actually buy) says it can draw up to 300W of power.
Your CPU and the other components in the system can probably draw near 200W, so the total power required for everything to run at peak load would be somewhere around 500 to 600 Watts.
Your power supply is already a whopping 1600W which is enough to be using multiple A6000 GPUs if you wanted.

Comment: You know I asked this question on other forums and I got simple yes answers, which I thankfull for as it conforms with the other answers I got such as here but your answer was really what I was hoping for, I actually have a much better understanding of what I am working and what to look out for on the market now. Thank you!